# How to grep a pdf for math?

Tags: grep, latex, math

Is there any way to grep a pdf document (originally written in LaTeX) for the math "2^n" as in 2 to the power of n?  I have pdfgrep but I don't know how you would use that to grep for math.

Answer (score 2):

You can use e.g. `mutool clean -d` from the `mupdf` package to decompress the streams in a PDF file, then you can look at it (or `grep` it directly).

Unfortunately, text in PDF files is rendered by placing glyphs (or sequences of glyphs) at pre-calculated coordinates. So both `$2^n$` and `$$2^n$$` will consist of two glyphs for `2` and `n` in different positions, and this is really difficult to match with a regular expression.

I suggest you decompress your pdf document and have a look at how the text rendering actually looks like.